# Help provide a proof for the following proposition?

Tags: real-analysis, probability

Anyone can help provide a proof or reference for the following proposition? Thanks!

> **Proposition 1.8.** Let $X$ be a random $k$-vector with a Lebesgue p.d.f. $f_X$ and let $Y=g(X)$, where $g$ is a Borel function from $(\mathcal{R}^k,\mathcal{B}^k)$ to $(\mathcal{R}^k,\mathcal{B}^k)$. Let $A_1,\dots,A_m$ be disjoint sets in $\mathcal{B}^k$ such that $\mathcal{R}^k-(A_1\cup \cdots \cup A_m)$ has Lebesgue measure $0$ and $g$ on $A_j$ is one-to-one with a nonvanishing Jacobian, i.e., the determinant $\operatorname*{Det}(\partial g(x)/\partial x)\neq 0$ on $A_j, j=1,\dots,m$. Then $Y$ has the following Lebesgue p.d.f.:
>   $$f_Y(x)=\sum_{j=1}^m [\operatorname*{Det}(\partial h_j(x)/\partial x)\mid f_X(h_j(x))$$
>   Where $h_j$ is the inverse function of $g$ on $A_j, j=1,\dots,m$.

Comment: This is Jun Shao isn't it?